# ssh segmentation fault

Tags: ssh, debian

i get segmentation fault when i try to ssh to a server, the ssh works in sudo mode but not at user mode.

these are the strace bits where the ssh breaks

```
open("/usr/include/pwd2.h", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
getpeername(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(222), sin_addr=inet_addr("xxx.xxx.xxx.xx")}, [16]) = 0
--- SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) @ 0 (0) ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
```

can anyone give me ideas about the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can anyone give me ideas about the problem?

Check packages:

```
# debsums openssh-server
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/openssh-server                                   OK
/usr/share/man/man5/sshd_config.5.gz                                          OK
/usr/share/man/man8/sshd.8.gz                                                 OK
/usr/share/man/man8/sftp-server.8.gz                                          OK
/usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server                                                  OK
/usr/sbin/sshd                                                                OK
```

Reinstall/upgrade openssh-server:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install openssh-server
```

Use gdb/valgrind to debug.

Comment: cool thanks, there was a problem in debsums, reinstall ssh and it works now!!!

Answer (score 2):

Man, you've got rootkit, reinstall!. Your ssh binary is trying to write down every password its using to that file, also keep in mind that every password that you see there was compromised.

Comment: It is a possibility, you can not be sure at this moment...

Comment: I had the same rootkit :/. Actually, why on earth the ssh client needs to write into a file suspiciously similar to /usr/include/pwd.h. I also traced one execution and saw the same, and the contents of the file was the password I used + the user + the hostname. These are the md5 of the files comprimised `5e080eb6c5aaef7e577cd37489080830  /usr/bin/ssh 337e9724f9eb005d2b8d4061284b1ae6  /usr/sbin/sshd`